# Zipping contents of a list file using DotNetZip library

Tags: c#

I have a .lst file that has the paths of various data that has to be zipped. The path may be a direct path to an executable or a path to a log file or may contain a wildcard like - c:\abc*.exe. How do I zip all of them into a single zip file? Thanks

DotNetZip Library is @:http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-examples&referringTitle=Examples

Contents of .lst file :

c:\log\abc.log

c:\log\def.log

c:\ping*.bat

c:\ping*.exe

This is what I tried:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())     
{                      
   StreamReader file = File.OpenText("C:\\pingman\\pingzipA.lst");
   string read = String.Empty;

   while ((read = file.ReadLine()) != null)                  
   {                                      
      zip.AddSelectedFiles(read, true);    
      zip.Save("c:\\update.zip");       
   }

   file.Close();   
}
```

Comment: the zip.save should be outside of the While loop for starters.. take a look at this Link this will give you several examples / Options that you can use..
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/384_Creating_ZIP_files_on_the_fly_in_ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I did try the zip.Save outside the while loop as it makes sense logically, but no good. I figured its something else with the code. As i am new to .Net technology.

Comment: @BigM: Yes, will work on it, Just updated it. Thanks

Comment: What do you get as a result after you move the Save outside the loop?

Comment: update.zip is still blank. The examples given in the documentation work when in standalone, but our list file has a mixture of direct path and also paths with wildcard characters. hence my confusion.

Comment: sounds like you need to make a List<string> and dynamically change the WildCard type and make it a param based of getting just the file ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 while ((read = file.ReadLine()) != null)                  
 {              
   if (read.Contains("*"))                        
   {
       zip.AddSelectedFiles(read, true);    
   }
   else
   {
       zip.AddFile(read);
   }
 }
 zip.Save("c:\\update.zip");
```

Comment: It works partially. The else section is getting executed. It does not add the path, if it contains a * I tried to modify it to-
if (read.Contains("*.") , but no good.

Comment: @user1620230 - I'm out of ideas, unfortunately.  I haven't used the library that extensively myself.

Comment: thank you, I worked on it today and found a way to get what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that has a TON of Examples take a look as use the examples to work for what you are trying to do.. there is even an example that uses Wild-Cards

[DontNetZip Library Site with Examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)

Comment: That is what I have been referring to :)

Comment: These examples helped and did work when we have the paths hardcoded. But our list file has a mixture of absolute paths and paths with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.

```
if (read.Contains("*"))
                    {
                        int i = read.IndexOf("*");
                        string path = read.Substring(0, i--);
                        string doc = read.Substring(i+1);
                        zip.AddSelectedFiles(doc, @path, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zip.AddFile(read);
                    }
```